# Pm2 passing command line args

Tags: pm2

I'm using PM2 to run an application (n8n) on a raspberry pi. I'm wanting n8n to be run with one of it's command line arguments: --tunnel to create a webhook tunnel to the app. I've set my ecosystem.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : "n8n",
    args:"--tunnel",
    env: {
      EXECUTIONS_DATA_PRUNE:true,
      EXECUTIONS_DATA_MAX_AGE=168,
      DB_SQLITE_VACUUM_ON_STARTUP=true,
      GENERIC_TIMEZONE:"Europe/London"
    },
    autorestart:true
  }]
}
```

I've also tried it with `args:"tunnel"` and using `node-args`. But to no avail...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below configuration for windows;

```
    module.exports = {
      apps : [{
        name   : "n8n",
        script : "C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\n8n\\bin\\n8n",
        args   : "start --tunnel" 
      }]
    }
```